# Error: The file or folder name contains characters that are not permitted. Please use a different name

Tags: powershell, backup, restore

I took backup from our staging server and restored on my local development machine. My Powershell script is not raising any error while restoration. But when I open the site in browser, it's giving me a weird error message:

```
The file or folder name contains characters that are not permitted.  Please use a different name.
```

PowerShell command I am using for backup and restore are:

On Staging server:

```
Backup-SPSite -Identity http://sp-stage -Path \\backup\sharepoint\test1\backup.bak
```

On my local machine:

```
Restore-SPSite -Identity http://sp-local -Path \\backup\sharepoint\test1\backup.bak
```

We are using custom master page and custom page layout for our site and my guess is that above error message is raising because of these custom master pages and page layouts.

Comment: Could you check the ULS log to see what it says?

Answer (score 2):

In SP, there are some special characters which are not allowed.
You can find them [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/905231).

Please make sure that these special characters are not being used in your site.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah, but assuming that a site has been created and backed up, it should not contain any not allowed characters, right?